# How to set default Controller and action method in Attribute routing in MVC5(Without using Convention based routing)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am implementing attribute routing in MVC5 for my application.

In the application i have some controllers,and each of them having some action methods,Now i want to make one of my   controller and action method as default for my application,without making the use of Convention based routing.

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Login")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        //Some body content
    }
     [Route("MyAccount")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyAccount()
    {
      //Some body content
    }
 }
```

Like that i have some other controllers and each of them has some action methods.

Now when i run my application,The first method which gets hitted is "Login" of the home controller,so in convention based routing it was hitting this method by default.But in Attribute Routing,i need to pass this controller name and action method http://{localhost}:8346/Home/Login.

So in the url i don't want to pass this Home controller name and Login action method.I want to make it default.So when i run my application it should hit this Login method.

How to achieve this.Any response will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        //Some body content
    }
    [Route("Home/MyAccount")]
    public ActionResult MyAccount()
    {
        //Some body content
    }
 }
```